# Find $a_0$ and $a_1$ when given a generating function.

Tags: generating-functions

The recursive sequence $a_n$ has the following generating function

$$\begin{align}
&f(x)={\frac{x}{1-2x}+{\frac{4}{1+3x}}}
\end{align}$$

I am to find $a_0$ and $a_1$:

Rule: ${\frac{1}{1-a}}=1+a+a^2+a^3+...+a^n$

So we have

${\frac{1}{1-2x}}=1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+...+2^{n-1}x^{n-1}+2^nx^n$

${\frac{1}{1+3x}}=1-3x+9x^2-27x^3+...+(-3)^{n-1}x^{n-1}+(-3)^nx^n$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
&f(x)={\frac{x}{1-2x}+{\frac{4}{1+3x}}}\\
&f(x)= x(1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+...) + 4(1-3x+9x^2-27x^3+...)\\
&f(x)= x+2x^2+4x^3+8x^4+... + 4-12x+36x^2-108x^3+...
\end{align}$$

For $a_0$ we have: $x+4=0+4=4$ , but when I try to calculate $a_1$ I get the wrong answer. The right answer should be $a_1=-11$, but I get

$$\begin{align}
&a_1=x+2x^2+4-12x=1+2+4-12=-5
\end{align}$$

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to find $a_1$?

Comment: $x-12x=-11x=a_1x.\;$  And you left out $...$ in your rule and a couple of equations after that

Comment: Yes, but how do I get to this conclusion. This is where I am lost..

Comment: $a_1$ is simply the coefficient on $x^1$

Comment: AH, thank you! Sometimes I blank on the simplest things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}f(x) &= x+2x^2 + 4x^3+ \dots + 4 - 12 x + 36 x^2 - 108x^3 + \dots \\&= 4-11x+38x^2-104x^3+\dots\\&=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\dots\end{align}

where the last line is precisely the definition of a generating function. There is no need to substitute any values of $x$.

Alternatively we have $a_n = \dfrac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, where $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n$th derivative. This might be useful for some other $f$.